# Get all possible data from list

Tags: python

```
L1 = "123abcd" #type: string
L2 = "456fghi" #type: string
L3 = "789vwxy" #type: string
    
L=[L1,L2,L3]
n=0
for l in L:
 n+=1

i=0;
while i > -1:
 Lt = L[1+i][2:5]+L[2+i][5:7]+L[0+i][:2] # Every new form list len == 7
 L.append(Lt)
 i+=1
```

how do I get all possible lists (3^7=2187) without the duplicate lists. Using this:

```
Lt = L[1+i][2:5]+L[2+i][5:7]+L[0+i][:2]
```

Duplicate lists might happen in the process to form new list but need to be excluded at the end.

Comment: you're missing a ':' at the end of your for and while lines

Comment: you don't need the L=[] line either, and I was wondering what is n for?

Comment: It looks like there is an indentation error (5 last lines should be indented to be part of the `for` statement) abd I do not see how you will end the `while` loop. Finally, I'm not sure you can use `n` like you did in `Ln` (I assume that's your objective?)

Comment: replace the first for loop with just `n = len(L)`

Comment: @GerardoZinno they don't actually use n, so I don't know if it's needed at all. Am waiting for OP to clarify

Comment: the n to define the index for the first 3 input lines in list. I use it so the form new list have them three to start the all list

Comment: @LeaC what do you use n for though? You get it by working out the length of the original L (which as Gerardo said can be done by len(L)) but then you never actually use it, so I don't know if it's necessary?

Comment: @Christophe I change  to Lt to avoid confusion.

Comment: your current method will only generate 16 different strings, which it will continuously repeat for ever (because your while loop will never terminate).

Comment: @EmiOB Yes I knew that, if I put break when the first same result occur it's only generate 16. is there a way to work on this so the expecting result of 343 can be collect.

Comment: @EmiOB is it possible when the same string occur, instead the same string added to the list why not add the first input string(L1) or second string(L2) etc. so it's can be use to generate new different ones and it'll keep repeat until no more new different strings.

Or when the same result occur that same string which will be added get indexes, ex: 6fgxy12 (same string) that occur, the string that get append "fgxy126" (the character 6 at 0 index move to the end) instead "6fgxy12".

Comment: This just feels like a very odd/inefficient way to get all the different ways to arrange the 21 characters across the 3 different lists. There was an answer yesterday which looked like a much better way to find all the different arrangements of the charecters.

Comment: To remove duplicates, you can do set(Lt) at the end.